# Ideal Quotient and Zero Locus.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I stumbled across something I couldn't get while reading.

So given two ideals $I$ and $J$ in some ring $R$ where $R = k[\mathbb{A}^n]$.

I want to show that $Z(I) - Z(J)$ $\subset$ $Z((I:J))$, where $(I:J)$ is the ideal quotient and $(I - J)$ is the set $I$ without $J$

Well, $Z(I) - Z(J) = \{x \in \mathbb{A}^n |f(x) = 0, f\in I, f\notin J\}$ and $Z((I:J)) = \{x\in \mathbb{A}^n | f(x)g(x) = 0, fg \in I, \forall g \in J \}$.

I want to progress further with the first set I have but, I can't really figure it out. Any suggestions to go further? It seems a bit trivial from how the set is defined, but I think I might be overthinking it.

My thoughts so far:

Suppose that $f \in I$ and $f \notin J$, but since $I$ is an ideal, this implies $fg \in I$ for all $g \in k[\mathbb{A}^n]$ and clearly $fg \in I$ for all $g \in J$ so $I \subset (I:J)$.

So suppose that $f \in Z(I) - Z(J)$ then for $x \in \mathbb{A^n}$, we have that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{A^n}$ such that $f \in Z(I)$ and $f \notin Z(J)$. I'm stuck here, I want to use a similar argument as I did for showing that $I \subset (I:J)$ but pretty sure I can't.

Comment: $k$ is a field?

Comment: @Eoin Yes it is.

Comment: For $J=0$ your assertion states $Z(I) \subset Z(R)$, which is obviously wrong.

Comment: I think you mean $Z(I)-Z(J) \subset Z(I:J)$, right?

Comment: @MooS Yes! Sorry for such a silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Your description of $Z(I) - Z(J)$ is just wrong. An element $x \in Z(I)-Z(J)$ is characterized by the fact, that $f(x)=0$ for each $f \in I$, and there exists $g \in J$ with $g(x) \neq 0$.

Now let $h \in (I:J)$. Take $g \in J$ from above and look at $(hg)(x)$.